# SSRS multiple single cells

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to figure out best way to add multiple fields to a SSRS report.
Report has some plots and tablix which are populated from queries but now I have been asked to add a table with ~20 values. The problem is that I need to have them in a specific order/layout (that I cannot obtain by sorting) and they might need to have a description added above which will be static text (not from the DB).

I would like to avoid situation where I keep 20 copy of the same query which returns single cell where the only difference would be in: 
`WHERE myTable.partID = xxxx`
Any chance I could keep a single query which takes that string like a parameter which I could specify somehow via expression or by any other means?
Not a classical SSRS parameter as I need a different one for each cell... 
Or will I need to create 20 queries to fetch all those single values and then put them as separate textfields on the report?

Comment: Could you add an OrderBy column to the database? That way you can pull all 20ish rows with one query. If not you can do a large case statement to determine OrderBy.

Comment: If you cannot provide logic for what order to sort your data, how can they have a specific order? There is either logic behind it, or there isn't; even if that logic is something as abstract as something like "Apples, is first, then oranges, then bananas, then strawberries, etc"

Comment: @KeithL: the results that I'm fetching are in form of ID, Value, timestamp.
For this section of report I need to get the most recent value that has been logged for each of those 20 IDs additionally to make it harder the table layout that I have been asked to use is to keep this data in 10Cx2R. They are grouped in pairs according to their functionality which is not defined in DB.

Comment: @Larnu I haven't said that that there is no logic, I only said that it is not one that I could sort by. Those records that I will get from DB would be 20 different devices states that on report are aligned in the functional groups that they create which is not defined in DB. There are no fields that I could use to sort them in the way they should be on the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've done this in the past, I build a single query that gets all the data I need with some kind of key.

For example I might have a list of captions and values, one per row, that I need to display as part of a report page. The dataset query might look something like ...

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Key varchar(20), Amount float, Caption varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @t
SELECT 'TotalSales', SUM(Amount), NULL AS Amount FROM myTable WHERE CountryID = @CountryID 
UNION 
SELECT 'Currency', NULL, CurrencyCode FROM myCurrencyTable WHERE CountryID = @CountryID
UNION 
SELECT 'Population', Population, NULL FROM myPopualtionTable WHERE CountryID = @CountryID

SELECT * FROM @t
```

The resulting dataset would look like this.

```
Key           Amount    Caption
'TotalSales'  12345     NULL
'Currency'    NULL      'GBP'
'Population'  62.3      NULL
```

Lets say we call this dataset `dsStuff` then in each cell/textbox the xpression would simply be something like.

```
=LOOKUP("Population", Fields!Key.Value, Fields!Amount.Value, "dsStuff")
```

or

```
=LOOKUP("Currency", Fields!Key.Value, Fields!Caption.Value, "dsStuff")
```

Comment: I looked at the vLookup and I think It might be the way to go. At least I will avoid the mess of keeping the 20 separate datasets.